# Laravel 6 Expected response code 220 but got an empty response using on digital ocean

Tags: php, laravel, email

Expected response code 220 but got an empty response.

I have laravel 6 app which contains the contacts form. that application is uploaded on digital ocean. 
I tried to send mail from my contact us form but i could not able to send it please help.

I have gmail account where i put my gmail account into less secure and activated 2 steps verification and generate app password. i added that app password into my .ENV file but i could able to send email.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Why you have smtp.mailtrap.io mail host in your .env if you want to use gmail?

Comment: MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

Comment: Did you cleared config cache ?

Comment: yes i did. but still got same.

Comment: Did you try with `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`?

Comment: yes i did even chane the port no for ssl or tls.

Comment: Try chaging `MAIL_PORT=587`  then `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
    MAIL_MAILER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=MY_EMAIL
    MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=MY_EMAIL (Again in my case)
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

And

```
    php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

change mail.php file in config to this :

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => '<<email address>>', 'name' => ''],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

and after setting env file dont forget to config:cache